# How to write to div dynamically, can be multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write text to a div dynamically.

I have this piece of jquery:

```
            $.each($('.LineShoppingCart'), function () {

            $("#itemPreview").html($(this).html());


        });
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="itemOrderPreview"></div>
```

It works partially because it does not work when .LineShoppingCart has multiple values. It only writes the last value.

If I write the jquery with an alert, for example:

```
            $.each($('.LineShoppingCart'), function () {
            alert($(this).html());


        });
```

Then I can see the alert popping up multiple times one for each value.

What do I have to do differently when writing the value to a div?

Many thanks.

Comment: No related Ids and Classes between your javascript code and your html .. so please provide a related html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `append`:

```
$.each($('.LineShoppingCart'), function () {
    $("#itemPreview").append($(this).html());
});
```

To learn about `append`: http://api.jquery.com/append/

To learn about `prepend`: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla js:

```
var preview = document.getElementById("itemPreview");
document.getElementsByTagName("LineShoppingCart").forEach(function (el) {
  preview.innerHTML += el.innerHTML;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mspzLz81/